# jquery add element if not present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading a book on jQuery and it has some simple tasks and examples.

I'm trying out the adding of an element to a table, but only if the item is not yet present.

The table is this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Spaghetti</td>
    <td>Karl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pasta</td>
    <td>David</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is: we're not allowed to add any classes or id's.

The idea is to add a caption. And of course, if the button is pressed 2 times, no second caption is added.

I tried this:

```
if(!jQuery.contains('table','caption')) {
    $('table').append('<caption>Orders</caption>');
}
```

And this

```
if(!($("table:contains('caption')"))) {
    $('table').append('<caption>Orders</caption>');
}
```

But neither work. I've read the jQuery api on the functions and selectors, I thought these would work but they don't. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get it done without the `if()` statement if you'd like:

```
$('table:not(:has(caption))').prepend('<caption>Orders</caption>');
```

This uses the [`not-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and the [`has-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to select `<table>` elements that do not have a nested `<caption>` element.

It also uses the [`prepend()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method to give a more expected placement in the DOM. It won't affect the actual display on the page.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the "not" selector.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
if($("table caption").length === 0) {
  // append caption
}
```

The jQuery call returns all the caption elements present inside all table elements. `.length` returns the count of the elements. If it's 0, append the caption.

Comment: I would do `if($('table caption').length == 0) { /* append caption */ }`

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't `if (!$('table caption').length)` work just as well, and be a little more concise?

Comment: David, I had that in my answer, but I removed it a few minutes ago. IMO `== 0` seems to be easier to comprehend.

Comment: Not working. When I do this: `alert($("table caption").length() == 0);` It gives nothing as result.

Comment: It's `.length`, not `.length()`.